# Shopify Custom Checkout Flow

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

**When using Shopify, is it possible to build a fully custom *checkout flow UI*, while still having the actual checkout processed by Shopify?**

The point is, I need to capture additional data during checkout.

Shopify provides a large number of different APIs, but I can't find anything to build a custom checkout flow. It seems like whatever API I look into, it ends up using their checkout flow "black box"?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **no**. You cannot capture any info during checkout. Capture it before checkout in the cart, or after checkout in the order confirmation.

Comment: Can none of their APIs do this? I was thinking to build my own checkout flow and submit it programmatically?

Comment: What about https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/sell-through-the-checkout-api#updating-a-checkout

Comment: Right then you make your own Sales Channel using that SDK, and then you can use the Checkout API. I thought you were just using normal Shopify...

Comment: I did mention APIs in the question. But even with the Checkout API, will I be able to store additional data? It looks like you can only send certain information to the API?

Comment: Well, looking at a the checkout you create and can patch, the checkout has the notes and attributes of an order... so why not stuff your extras in there.